# Generate image from text response with correct extension

Tags: php, laravel, image, api, mime

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://stagingadmin.zenpepper.com/image/5b1a35e54a77da5969f1f98d?token=HIDDEN",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Postman-Token: HIDDEN",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I have a api call that returns image as text and that image can be converted to image. But i want to save that image with correct extension in laravel

Currently i have below code but i want to try a better solution.

```
if (!file_exists(public_path() . '/images/' . $image_id . '.png')) {

    if (strpos($response, 'PNG') !== false || strpos($response, 'png') !== false) {
        Image::make($response)->save(public_path('images/' . $image_id . ".png"));
    }
}

if (!file_exists(public_path() . '/images/' . $image_id . '.jpg')) {

    if (strpos($response, 'jpg') !== false || strpos($response, 'JPG') !== false) {
        Image::make($response)->save(public_path('images/' . $image_id . ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to save a file in Laravel.

```
if($response)
   {
      $path = 'images/' . $image_id;
      $fileName = str_replace(' ', '_', response->getClientOriginalName());
      $response->storeAs($path,$fileName);
   }
```

For more [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

I think is a better way to use file storage driver in `Laravel`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem

To the determinate type of file, you can read `MIME` Type.